# Whether to submit mixed GRE scores?

Tags: graduate-admissions, graduate-school, gre

I wrote the GRE recently and got very divergent scores. I scored exceptionally high in Verbal reasoning (168/170, which is 98th percentile) but exceptionally low in quantitative reasoning (147/170, which is 25th percentile). I will be applying to political science programs which have quantiative components, but to a subfield (with a research topic) completely unrelated to quantitative methods. Wondering if anyone has any advice on whether I should send in my scores to schools who have made it optional, since the high verbal score might help my application quite a bit, or if it is not worth the risk of being doomed via my low quant score.

Thanks

Comment: Will you need to pass quantitative classes or qualifying exams?